# How to blocked/Inactivate Uwp app title bar due to show ContentDialog?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, contentdialog

I need to blocked/Inactivate whole Uwp app with title bar due to show ContentDialog. I have used the code from Microsoft XAML Controls Gallery App, Whereas Control-Gallery app properly blocked the whole application but my test app is not blocking the app.

[image]

This is another screen shoot after adding `winui:XamlControlsResources ControlsResourcesVersion="Version2"` in Resource dictionary. Which can also be achieved by overriding `SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush`.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush" Color="#000000" Opacity="0.18"/>
```

Or

```
<Application
x:Class="App2.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App2"
xmlns:winui="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <winui:XamlControlsResources ControlsResourcesVersion="Version2" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>            
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

[image]

Here is the used sample code:

```
<Page
x:Class="App2.ContentDialogContent"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <!--  Content body  -->
    <TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipisicing elit." TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <CheckBox Content="Upload your content to the cloud." />
</StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Button click:

```
    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog();
        dialog.Title = "Save your work?";
        dialog.PrimaryButtonText = "Save";
        dialog.SecondaryButtonText = "Don't Save";
        dialog.CloseButtonText = "Cancel";
        dialog.DefaultButton = ContentDialogButton.Primary;
        dialog.Content = new ContentDialogContent();

        var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();

        if (result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
        {
            //DialogResult.Text = "User saved their work";
        }
        else if (result == ContentDialogResult.Secondary)
        {
            //DialogResult.Text = "User did not save their work";
        }
        else
        {
            //DialogResult.Text = "User cancelled the dialog";
        }
      }
```

I have used `ExtendViewIntoTitleBar`, but the problem remains with title bar's system button area.

[image]

Comment: Do you also set https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplicationviewtitlebar.extendviewintotitlebar?view=winrt-22000 to `true` as the [Gallery App does](https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery/blob/e97be1ead343cc6d9b6646a056431bdffe7c75d8/XamlControlsGallery/App.xaml.cs#L113)?

Comment: please try to set ApplicationViewTitleBar  button background color as transparent like following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sir Rufo said, your expected view has been set `ExtendViewIntoTitleBar` as true that could extend your view content into title bar. and it could make whole current view content block by `ContentDialog`.

For using [`ExtendViewIntoTitleBar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplicationviewtitlebar.extendviewintotitlebar?view=winrt-22000), [please refer to Title bar customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=wasdk).

```
var coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
```

Update

You need to set your title bar button background color as transparent.

```
ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
```